# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'educationDetails'

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement Form Array in custom multi-step form using Angular-12.

Component:

```js
export class ProfileEditComponent implements OnInit {

  isLinear = true;
  isLoading = false;
  isSubmitted = false;
  multistepForm!: FormGroup;
  step: any = 1;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    this.step = this.step + 1;
  }

  previous() {
    this.step = this.step - 1;
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.multistepForm = this.fb.group({
      //  multistepDetails: new FormGroup({
      personalDetails: new FormGroup({
        first_name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
        last_name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
        other_name: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      }),
      educations: this.fb.array([
        this.createEducation()

      ])
    });
  }

  createEducation() {
    return this.fb.group({
      educationDetails: new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
        country: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3))
      }),
    })
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="multistepForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <div class="card-body" *ngIf="step == 1" formGroupName="personalDetails">
    <h4>Personal Details</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">First Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Other Name:</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="other_name" placeholder="Other Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Last Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="last Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" *ngIf="step == 2" formGroupName="educationDetails">
    <h4>Education Details</h4>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" *ngIf="step == 3">
    <h4>Review</h4>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-navy margins" *ngIf="step != 1" (click)="previous()">Previous</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="step != 3">Next</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="step == 3">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Whenever I click on Next button to take me to Education, I got this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'educationDetails'
> at _throwError (forms.js:1721)
> at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:1694)
> at FormGroupDirective._setUpFormContainer (forms.js:5338)

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `createEducation()` this method in `ngOnInit`

Comment: Is my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 2 you have not given educations formArray reference in HTML. So to get those Formarray or Forgroup[] you need to create one property on your ProfileEditComponent as below:

```
get educations(): FormGroup[] {
    return (<FormArray>this.multistepForm.controls['educations']).controls as FormGroup[];
}
```

This will return you all the educations in the form of FormGroup[]. Now you have to use this to bind your controls on HTML. So in your HTML you need to change your step 2 this way:

```
<div class="card-body" *ngIf="step == 2">
    <div *ngFor="let item of educations; index as i">
      <div [formGroup]="item">
        <div formGroupName="educationDetails">
          <h4>Education Details</h4>
          <hr>
          <div>
            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="city">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="country">Country:</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="country">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My case is using other's share component, and the share component use
***zone*** and ***setTimeout*** to build the formGroup and formArray. ***So the life cycle was not in my expected***.

When data binding or even you use console.log to print, ***the formGroup and formControl is truly exist***. But it always return *ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'formControl'*. That's how the ***zone*** and ***setTimeout*** make an impact.

Finally, I set *ngIf="formGroup" in all the tag which has [FormGroup] =[formGroup]. So whatever formGroup is exist or not, it works fine.

```
<!-- which has [formGroup]="fg", add *ngIf="fg" -->
<div [formGroup]="fg" ***ngIf="fg"**>...</div>
```